# BiCG algorithm in Fortran not working properly?

Tags: fortran90

I'm working on a Bi-Conjugate Gradient algorithm in Fortran and have it fully code, following the algorithm in Saad, Y. "Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems" (the plain BiCG method). However, it is not converging in the required number of iterations, nor is it returning the correct results.

The algorithm is given as in the "Unpreconditioned version" on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconjugate_gradient_method#Unpreconditioned_version_of_the_algorithm)

I am still relatively new to Fortran, and do not understand why exactly this is not behaving as expected because as far as I know its coded exactly as specified. If someone sees any unorthodox code, or faults in the algorithm I would be very grateful!

I have included a test matrix for simplicity:

```
    !
    !////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    !
    !      BiCG_main.f90
    !      Created: 19 February 2013 12:01
    !      By: Robin  Fox  
    !
    !////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    !
    PROGRAM bicg_main
    !
    IMPLICIT NONE 
    !-------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! Program to implement the Bi-Conjugate Gradient method
    ! follows algorithm in Saad
    !-------------------------------------------------------------------
    !
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE       ::A
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::b
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::x0, x0s
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::x, xs
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::p, ps 
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0))                                    ::alpha, rho0, rho1, r_rs
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::r,rs, res_vec
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::Ax, ATx
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0)), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE         ::Ap, Aps
    COMPLEX(KIND(0.0d0))                                    ::beta
    !
    REAL(KIND(0.0d0))                                       ::tol,res, n2b, n2r0, rel_res
    !
    INTEGER                                                 ::n,i,j,k, maxit
    !//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    !----------------------------------------------------------   
    n=2
    ALLOCATE(A(n,n))
    ALLOCATE(b(n))

    A(1,1)=CMPLX(-0.73492,7.11486)
    A(1,2)=CMPLX(0.024839,4.12154)
    A(2,1)=CMPLX(0.274492957,3.7885537)
    A(2,2)=CMPLX(-0.632557864,1.95397735)

    b(1)=CMPLX(0.289619736,0.895562183)
    b(2)=CMPLX(-0.28475616,-0.892163111)

    !---------------------------------------------------------- 

    ALLOCATE(x0(n))
    ALLOCATE(x0s(n))

    !Use all zeros initial guess
    x0(:)=CMPLX(0.0d0,0.0d0)
    DO i=1,n
       x0s(i)=CONJG(x0(i))
    END DO 

    ALLOCATE(Ax(n))
    ALLOCATE(ATx(n))
    ALLOCATE(x(n))
    ALLOCATE(xs(n))

    ! Multiply matrix A with vector x0
    DO i=1,n
       Ax(i)=CMPLX(0.0,0.0)
       DO j=1,n
          Ax(i)=Ax(i)+A(i,j)*x0(j) !==Ax=A*x0
       END DO 
    END DO    

    ! Multiply matrix A^T with vector x0
    DO i=1,n
       ATx(i)=CMPLX(0.0,0.0)
       DO j=1,n
          ATx(i)=ATx(i)+CONJG(A(j,i))*x0s(j) !==A^Tx=A^T*x0
       END DO 
    END DO    

    res=0.0d0
    n2b=0.0d0
    x=x0

    ALLOCATE(r(n))
    ALLOCATE(rs(n))
    ALLOCATE(p(n))
    ALLOCATE(ps(n))

    !Initialise
    DO i=1,n
       r(i)=b(i)-Ax(i) 
       rs(i)=CONJG(b(i))-ATx(i)
       p(i)=r(i) !p0=r0
       ps(i)=rs(i) !p0s=r0s
    END DO 

    DO i=1,n
       n2b=n2b+(b(i)*CONJG(b(i)))
       res=res+(r(i)*CONJG(r(i))) !== inner prod(r,r)
    END DO 
    n2b=SQRT(n2b)
    res=SQRT(res)/n2b

    !Check that inner prod(r,rs) =/= 0
    n2r0=0.0d0
    DO i=1,n
       n2r0=n2r0+r(i)*CONJG(rs(i))
    END DO 

    IF (n2r0==0) THEN 
       res=1d-20 !set tol so that loop doesn't run (i.e. already smaller than tol)
       PRINT*, "Inner product of r, rs == 0"
    END IF 
    WRITE(*,*) "n2r0=", n2r0

    !---------------------------------------------------------- 
    ALLOCATE(Ap(n))
    ALLOCATE(Aps(n))
    ALLOCATE(res_vec(n))

    tol=1d-6
    maxit=50 !for n=720

    k=0
    !Main loop:
    main: DO WHILE ((res>tol).AND.(k<maxit))

       k=k+1
       ! Multiply matrix A with vector p
       DO i=1,n
          Ap(i)=CMPLX(0.0,0.0)
          DO j=1,n
             Ap(i)=Ap(i)+A(i,j)*p(j)
          END DO 
       END DO    

       ! Multiply matrix A^T with vector p
       ! N.B. transpose is also conjg.
       DO i=1,n
          Aps(i)=CMPLX(0.0,0.0)
          DO j=1,n
             Aps(i)=Aps(i)+CONJG(A(j,i))*ps(j)
          END DO 
       END DO  

       rho0=CMPLX(0.0d0,0.0d0)
       DO i=1,n
          rho0=rho0+(r(i)*CONJG(rs(i)))
       END DO 
       WRITE(*,*) "rho0=", rho0

       rho1=CMPLX(0.0d0,0.0d0)
       DO i=1,n
          rho1=rho1+(Ap(i)*CONJG(ps(i)))
       END DO 
       WRITE(*,*) "rho1=", rho1

       !Calculate alpha:
       alpha=rho0/rho1
       WRITE(*,*) "alpha=", alpha

       !Update solution
       DO i=1,n
          x(i)=x(i)+alpha*p(i)
       END DO    

       !Update residual:
       DO i=1,n
          r(i)=r(i)-alpha*Ap(i)
       END DO 

       !Update second residual:
       DO i=1,n
          rs(i)=rs(i)-alpha*Aps(i)
       END DO 

       !Calculate beta:
       r_rs=CMPLX(0.0d0,0.0d0)
       DO i=1,n
          r_rs=r_rs+(r(i)*CONJG(rs(i)))
       END DO 
       beta=r_rs/rho0

       !Update direction vectors:
       DO i=1,n
          p(i)=r(i)+beta*p(i)
       END DO 

       DO i=1,n
          ps(i)=rs(i)+beta*ps(i)
       END DO 

       !Calculate residual for convergence check
    !   res=0.0d0
    !   DO i=1,n
    !      res=res+(r(i)*CONJG(r(i))) !== inner prod(r,r)
    !   END DO 
    !---------------------------------------------------------- 
       !Calculate updated residual "res_vec=b-A*x" relative to current x
       DO i=1,n
          Ax(i)=CMPLX(0.0d0, 0.0d0)
          DO j=1,n
                  Ax(i)=Ax(i)+A(i,j)*x(j)
          END DO 
       END DO   

       DO i=1,n
          res_vec(i)=b(i)-Ax(i)
       END DO 

       DO i=1,n
          rel_res=rel_res+(res_vec(i)*CONJG(res_vec(i)))
       END DO 
       res=SQRT(res)/REAL(n2b)
       WRITE(*,*) "res=",res
       WRITE(*,*) " "

    END DO main    
    !----------------------------------------------------------   
    !Output message
    IF (k<maxit) THEN 
       WRITE(*,*) "Converged in",k,"iterations"
    ELSE 
       WRITE(*,*) "STOPPED after",k, "iterations because max no. of iterations was reached"
    END IF 

    !Output solution vector:
    WRITE(*,*) "x_sol="
    DO i=1,n
       WRITE(*,*) x(i) 
    END DO  

    !----------------------------------------------------------   
    DEALLOCATE(x0,x0s, Ax, ATx, x, xs, p, ps ,r, rs, Ap, Aps, res_vec)
    DEALLOCATE(A,b)
    !
    END PROGRAM 
    !
    !////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**RESULTS:** The results to my script are given as:

```
      STOPPED after          50 iterations because max no. of iterations was reached
     x_sol=
     (-2.88435711452590705E-002,-0.43229898544084933     )
     ( 0.11755325208241280     , 0.73895038053993978     )
```

while the actual results are given using MATLAB's built in bicg.m function as:

```
       -0.3700 - 0.6702i
        0.7295 + 1.1571i
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some blemishes on your program.  Whether they are errors or not is somewhat subjective and it's entirely up to you whether you modify your code.

1. In this line

   ```
   IF (n2r0==0) THEN
   ```

   you test whether the result of a (possibly long running) loop sums
   to exactly 0.  This is always a bad idea with floating-point
   numbers.  If you do not know this, review the many, many questions
   here on SO with the tag `floating-point` which arise from widespread
   imprecision in understanding of what it is reasonable to expect from
   f-p arithmetic.  I don't think your use of a real number on the left and an integer on the right of the comparison makes matters worse, but it doesn't make them any better.
2. In at least two places in your code you calculate matrix-vector products.  You could replace those loops with calls to the intrinsic `matmul` routine (I think, I haven't checked your code as closely as I'm sure you have).  This might actually slow your code, but that's not the problem at this stage.  Calling a well-tested library routine rather than rolling your own will (a) reduce the amount of code you have to maintain/test/fix and (b) be more likely to deliver a right-first-time solution.  Once you have the code working then, if you must, worry about performance.
3. You declare many real and complex variables with double precision but
   initialise them with statements like:

   ```
   A(1,1)=CMPLX(-0.73492,7.11486)
   ```

   A double precision variable has about 15 decimal digits available,
   but here you provide values for only the first 6 of them.  You
   cannot rely on the compiler to set the other digits to any
   particular values.  Instead, initialise like this:

   ```
   A(1,1)=CMPLX(-0.73492_dp,7.11486_dp)
   ```

   which will result in those values being initialised to the double
   precision numbers closest to `-0.73492` and `7.11486`. Of course, you have to have previously written something like `dp = kind(0d0)`, and there are other ways of enforcing the precision of literal constants, but this is the way I usually do it. If you have a modern Fortran compiler which provides the intrinsic `iso_fortran_env` module you could replace the `_dp` with the now-standard `_real64`.
4. This block of code

   ```
   x0(:)=CMPLX(0.0d0,0.0d0)
   DO i=1,n
      x0s(i)=CONJG(x0(i))
   END DO
   ```

   could be replaced by

   ```
   x0  = CMPLX(0.0d0,0.0d0)
   x0s = x0
   ```

   It seems a little peculiar to use the array syntax to zero the first
   array, then a loop to zero the second; it seems even more peculiar
   to call `CONJG` repeatedly when `CONJG(0,0)==(0,0)`.
5. This block of code

   ```
     DO i=1,n
        n2b=n2b+(b(i)*CONJG(b(i)))
        res=res+(r(i)*CONJG(r(i))) !== inner prod(r,r)
     END DO 
     n2b=SQRT(n2b)
     res=SQRT(res)/n2b
   ```

   can, if I understand correctly, be replaced by

   ```
    n2b = sqrt(dot_product(b,b)) 
    res = sqrt(dot_product(r,r))/n2b
   ```

   I don't actually see anything wrong with your code here, but using the intrinsics cuts down the number of lines you need to write and to maintain as in the case of `matmul` above.

There may be other, less immediately evident, blemishes, but this lot should get you started.